# C# serial link byte communication error

Tags: c#, byte

i would like to ask you, because i´m not able to solve my problem. I programmed a communication between MCU and PC (windows) and there is a problem.

Type of communication: Byte 
message struct:
PC-> MCU AA 55 MESLEN MESSID PACKID[1] PACKID[0] DATA CRC; 
MCU->PC 55 AA MESID DATA1 DATA0 CRC (fixed size).

where AA 55 (55 AA) are message headers

Principle of communication:
PC sent a amonout of data (with mess ID, packedID etc)

MCU receieve data and in case if data are OK (Header and CRC is OK) sent a responce with same messID and packedID to confirm previous message. If not, "watchdog" resend a message (and write to console timeout).

The communication works without problem except one case. In case of DATA0 = 0x1A and DATA1 =0x00, communication totally failed.

I check the commnunication using a osciloscope and this message is sent correctly with any delays etc.

Problem specific: 
1)Only in this case, communication failed. 
2)Only in this case PC receive bytes from serial link with big delay but data are sent correctly (checked on osciloscope).

I tried:
change a timeouts
change a receive byte treshold (now 1, but i tested 7B, but it is same problem)

rec. function source:

```
      static void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int BytesNr = port.BytesToRead;
        int InputCRC = 0;
        Uart_alldata = false;
        byte[] tempData = new byte[10];


        if (BytesNr == 7)
        {
            // port.Read(tempData, 0, BytesNr); 
            for (int i = 0; i < BytesNr; i++) tempData[i] = Convert.ToByte(port.ReadByte()); // alt for test
            Array.Copy(tempData, inbuffer, BytesNr);
            Uart_alldata = true;
            string data = BitConverter.ToString(tempData);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
        else
        {
            // port.Read(tempData, 0, pocetB); 
            for (int i = 0; i < BytesNr; i++) tempData[i] = Convert.ToByte(port.ReadByte());
            Array.Copy(tempData, inbuffer, BytesNr);

            string data = BitConverter.ToString(tempData);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
        }

        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort(ArrayComPortsNames[cislo_portu], 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            port.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
            port.WriteBufferSize = 4096;
            port.WriteTimeout = 500;
            port.ReadTimeout = 50;
            port.RtsEnable = true;
            port.DtrEnable = true;
            port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;


            // Begin communications
            port.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Port otevřen");
    }
```

`about 200 previous messages without problem
ReadBytes:7B
55-AA-02-00-17-CC-1C-00-00-00
ReadBytes:7B
55-AA-02-00-17-CC-1C-00-00-00
ReadBytes:7B
55-AA-02-00-18-CC-1B-00-00-00
ReadBytes:7B
55-AA-02-00-18-CC-1B-00-00-00
ReadBytes:7B
55-AA-02-00-19-CC-1A-00-00-00
ReadBytes:7B
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
55-AA-02-00-19-CC-1A-00-00-00
ReadBytes:7B
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
55-AA-02-00-1A-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
CC-19-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
55-AA-02-00-1A-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
CC-19-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
55-AA-02-00-1A-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
CC-19-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
55-AA-02-00-1A-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
CC-19-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00`

Do you have some ideas where is problem?? 
Thank you for your ideas.

Regards

L.Beran

Comment: EDIT: The data are receieved OK (header, data itself and CRC) but shifted.

Comment: I think your question will be more likely to get an answer if you tag it with more specific tags.  Eg. I didn't really know what an MCU was until I googled it, but I bet there are some hardware/embedded tags you could use to get those people's attention.